# Specifics - What does "chkdsk /f" really do under the hood?

Tags: windows

Yes... it "magically" fixes things with disk issues with tend to surface when you can't access a File or Folder via the Windows File Explorer and is presenting errors.

But, what is it actually doing under the hood?

Comment: basically it reads the filesystem metadata and then checks the actual info on disk to make sure that the filesystem metadata is correct, and if not it fixes it one way or another. the metadata can be considered a description of what should be, and chkdsk is looking to see if it actually is.

Comment: And if it finds errors, it will *try to fix the file system, at the expense of data.* Bad files are lumped together, and bad sectors removed from the file system, but this data is often not recoverable. If you believe there are file system issues, it's best to make a full disk image, ignoring bad sectors, so that you have recourse after Chkdsk cleans up, removing data.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK#Microsoft_Windows

Comment: I see, so basically tries to rebuild the Index of a Book based on the Contents of the Book (which may have pages ripped out and/or notes scribbled in). To use an analogy. That makes sense. So the obvious next question is... how does the Index / File System get messed up in the first place? Same was a a dodgy pixel on a monitor, aka. just bad luck/hardware/materials etc.?

Comment: You are getting it, but its kinda reversed. raw data on disk is unstructured from a file-system perspective (it has a hardware structure and a logical structure, but that does not extend up to the File level), so under most circumstances you are looking at the index first, and then looking to see if the data matches up. data that is not referenced by the index is basically lost, and there isn't a way to relink it unless you get into data recovery tools (specifically file carving utilities). That's what DrMoishe Pippik is referring to about repairs being at the expense of the data